# When do the restrictions of 3 weeks start when 17 Tammuz is on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, fast-days, mourning-aveilus, three-weeks

When do the restrictions of 3 weeks start when 17 Tammuz is on Shabbos (e.g. this year)?

Do they start motzei shabbos (already 18 Tammuz), since the 17 Tammuz is technically on shabbos or do they still start with the fast on Sunday morning?

(Of course, this question is only according to those who hold that the restrictions, such as not getting a haircut, generally start with the fast and not on the night of the 17th of Tammuz.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8523/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rav Moshe Feinstein ([Igrot Moshe OC 1:168](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=291&hilite=)) holds that in general one can have a wedding on the night of 17 Tammuz when necessary, but says in that same teshuva that for sure when the fast is Nidche that you can't have a wedding Saturday night. (I assume all other restrictions follow.)

Comment: I was wondering if the other restrictions of the fast(showering with hot water) starts at night when nidche?

Comment: @sam That I doubt because while the Three Weeks have started, the fast has not. I don't see why one would differentiate between eating and bathing.

Comment: @DoubleAA is a wedding allowed on a fast day? If the restrictions of a fast might start the night before then the wedding question is one determined by the fast, not the three weeks (if a wedding is not allowed on a fast day). A shehechyanu is allowed on a fast but not during the three weeks (according to Chabad and halachipedia). Could a shehechyanu be said Saturday night?

Comment: @Danno Why would part of the fast-restrictions start at one point and the rest later? That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DoubleAA The shehechyanu is not a fast restriction so if weddings are, then they might be proscribed because of fast restrictions but 3 weeks restrictions still might or might not have begun. My question is about starting 3 weeks restrictions the night before in general, and then in a year where the 17th of Tammuz is a shabbat all the more so.