# Showering after chatzos on Friday the 8th of Av

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav, showering-bathing, erev-shabbat, chatzos

This year the ninth of Av falls out on *Shabbos* which means that there are somewhat different laws that are practiced than in a typical year at this time (e.g. the fast is observed on Sunday). With regard to this, I just saw in a *halacha* sheet from Rabbi Yisrael Saperstein of Monsey, NY to shower *erev Shabbos* before *chatzos*. My (presumably errant) understanding had always been that, if anything, this *erev Shabbos* is not even really considered *shavua shechal bo* (the week of; according to the Talmudic law; Ashkenazim generally keep its customs from *Rosh Chodesh Av*), since the fast is deferred. What are the sources for/against this ruling (that one can shower before chatzot but not after) in contemporary (or earlier) authorities? Which communities do/don't have this custom?

Comment: You are not errant that we hold that it is not Shavua sheChal Bo. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17841/759

Answer (score 4):

What you are referring to is found in Simman 551:16. The Rema writes

```
.ואפילו בערב-שתב של 'חזון' אסור לרחוץ כי אם ראשו ופניו ידיו ורגליו בצונן
.ויש מקלים בחפיפת הראש בחמין למי שרגיל בכך כל שבת
```

On that statement the באור הלכה ד"ה בחפיפת הראש בחמין writes

```
ואפילו חל ערב-שבת של 'חזון' בערב תשעה באב
[ומכל מקום בזה יזהר לכתחילה שיהיה קדם חצות ,ובדעבד גם אחר חצות שרי [פמ"ג
```

So it's the Pri Megadim

Comment: The Peri Megadim is just quoting the Taz (sk 16) who is just quoting the Bach ([sv. V'Im](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2592)), so he seems to be the real culprit.

Comment: Incidentally, that means this practice dates from the times of weekday clothes on Shabbat Tisha b'Av and hence may be obsolete now when generally accepted halacha weighs the values of Kavod Shabbat and Innuyei Tisha b'Av differently.

Comment: The Mishnah Berurah still brings it though, even though he comments that we wear bigdei shabbas on shabbas

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that Sepharadim follow Rambam on this issue and do not refrain at all from showering / bathing during the nine days.  The only bathing that is prohibited is pleasure bathing, like going to a Greek style sauna / Turkish bath type thing where they have the hot room and cold room, which were fairly wide spread in the middle east.  I've never read about any prohibition on bathing after noon on the 8th of Av.

Every year before the nine days the Rabbi in our synagogue makes a special request that we all bath every day before coming to the synagogue.

[הלכות תענייות פרק ה,ו](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3905.htm#6)

> ו  משייכנס אב, ממעטין בשמחה.  ושבת שחל תשעה באב להיות בתוכה, אסור לספר ולכבס וללבוש כלי מגוהץ, אפילו כלי פשתן, עד שיעבור התענית; ואפילו לכבס ולהניח לאחר התענית, אסור.  וכבר נהגו ישראל, שלא לאכול בשר בשבת זו, ולא ייכנסו למרחץ, עד שיעבור התענית; ויש מקומות שנהגו לבטל השחיטה מראש החודש, עד התענית.
>
> ז  תשעה באב--לילו כיומו לכל דבר, ואין אוכלין אלא מבעוד יום; ובין השמשות שלו, אסור כיום הכיפורים.  ולא יאכל בשר ולא ישתה יין, בסעודה המפסיק בה; אבל שותה הוא יין מגיתו שיש לו שלושה ימים או פחות, ואוכל בשר מליח שיש לו שלושה ימים או יתר.  ולא יאכל שני תבשילין.
>
> ח  במה דברים אמורים, שאכל ערב תשעה באב אחר חצות; אבל אם סעד קודם חצות--אף על פי שהוא מפסיק בה, אוכל כל מה שירצה.  וערב תשעה באב שחל להיות בשבת--אוכל ושותה כל צורכו, ומעלה על שולחנו אפילו כסעודת שלמה; וכן תשעה באב עצמו שחל להיות בשבת, אינו מחסר כלום.
>
> ט  זו היא מידת כל העם, שאינן יכולין לסבול יותר מדיי.

Comment: Could someone comment on why the downvote?

Comment: Non-Jews seem just as relevant as the Sefardim you mention. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/i-know-a-and-based-on-a-im-asking-b#comment8372_2182

Comment: The question asks which communities do/don't have this custom, so I don't see why an answer about Sefardim isn't relevant.  The question didn't say which *Ashkenazi* communities.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Neither did the question in my link

Answer (score -4):

Just the opposite! There's less aveilus on Erev Shabbos after chatzos. The proof is that a mourner may ONLY shower AFTER chatzos

Comment: Can you source that a mourner may shower on Friday afternoon?