# Can a wedding lasting into the 3 weeks have music playing?

Tags: wedding, music, three-weeks

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29604/what-things-are-restricted-during-the-3-weeks/29607#29607) are things that are forbidden during the 3 weeks. If an Ashkenazi got married the evening of the 3 weeks before Shkiyah (which is similar to another question on this site), can the music continue playing after Shkiya for the duration of the wedding? Do we say that since the music started when permissible, one can finish or once Shkiya comes & brings the Issur of playing music with it, the music must cease?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are you allowed to get married the night going into Shiva Asar B'Tamuz?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8523/are-you-allowed-to-get-married-the-night-going-into-shiva-asar-btamuz)

Comment: @shalom the answers there don't address this aspect though. Probably it should be edited out of that wuestion post

Comment: Earl, of course it's permitted to play the music, just like eating meat at a Siyum! This is Simchat Mitzva of the highest caliber

Comment: @DoubleAA Is that true? If one makes a Siyum during the Three Weeks, can they play music? I was under the impression that it was only eating meat that was permitted during the Nine Days, and not that all the Hilchos Aveilus get suspended for a Seudas Mitzvah (if all the Hilchos Aveilus got suspended for a Seudas Mitzvah, then what would be the problem of getting married during the Three Weeks at all?). Also, do we consider the music a "continuation", like we do for food? Food has a defined start and end (the before and after Brachos), maybe each note of music is its' own issue.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Yes music at a siyum should be fine http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Three_Weeks#cite_note-76 and Kol SheKein to a wedding which is a bigger deal than a Siyum! Indeed you ask a good question, and if someone hasn't fulfilled pru urvu yet it's rather hard to justify not letting them get married. Especially if delaying 3 weeks is going to lead to extra Zera Levatalla or Negiat Ervah as is unfortunately too often the case nowadays. Better to skip on the late custom and do Mitzvot Deorayta properly.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm missing something about the timing of the wedding, here. The 3 weeks begins on 17 Tamuz, which is a public fast day. Are you talking about a wedding that starts on the afternoon of the 16th of Tamuz?

Comment: @DoubleAA The sources quoted there seem to all be quoting R' Yosef ZT"L. In general, Sephardim are a lot more lenient than Ashkenazim during the 3 weeks (and per an answer linked to this question, R' Yosef allowed weddings during most of the Three Weeks). It's understandable that music is allowed if you're allowed to have a wedding, but most Ashkenazim do Lema'aseh Pasken not to have a wedding. Would Ashkenazim Pasken like that as well?

Comment: @DanF yes say the wedding started an hour before Shkiya on the 16th of Tamuz.

Comment: @Shalom my question is regarding playing music at the wedding not the actual ceremony itself. Perhaps that question should be a related but not a duplicate

Comment: @DoubleAA that was my query. Is it comparable to making a siyum in the 9 days or not.

Comment: @Earl Of course it's not comparable. A wedding is a significantly better reason to allow for celebration than a mere Siyum. It's hard to imagine a more significant Simchat Mitzva than a wedding celebration.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170711190242/https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/

Comment: This is a very subtle nuanced difference from the proposed dupe - one asks about making the wedding lechatchilah, while this one asks about continuing the music once the wedding is ongoing, regardless of the answer to that one. I'm voting not a dupe.